# Filter the places list which inside the map projection?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a places `List` Which contains `Hospital` object(`List<Hospital>`). Hospital objects contain Name, latitude, longitude, and mobile number as an attribute.  If the user adjusts the screen I get the current map projection `LatLngBounds` from that I got covered area. So Now **I want to filter the Hospitals Which inside the that `LatLngBounds`**, How can I implement `getAvailableHospital()` method? Thank you!

> Hospital Object Class

```
Class Hospital
{
    private String Name;
    private String Latitude;
    private String Longtitude;
    private String PhoneNumber
}
```

> Inside the Map Fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        getAvailabelHospitals(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude, bounds.southwest.longitude, bounds.southwest.latitude);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LatLngBounds has a [contains method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) that takes a LatLng and returns true if the LatLng is within the bounds.

To generate a list of hospitals within the bounds, check whether each item in your list is contained within the bounds. For example:

```
List<Hospital> inBounds = hospitals
      .stream()
      .filter(h -> bounds.contains(new LatLng(h.latitude(), h.longitude()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Happy to get an answer from the Girl Programmer!!!, Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<fshop> Rlist;

Rlist=new ArrayList<>();
        for(fshop f : mlist)
        {
            LatLng point = new LatLng (Double.parseDouble(f.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(f.getLng()));
            if(bounds.contains(point))
            {
                Rlist.add(f);
            }
        }
```